# Java class methods do not auto complete in Jython using Eclipse Pydev

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jython, pydev

I'm using PyDev 2.5 with Eclipse Indigo and Jython 2.5.3b1 . I have a JAR file that contains certain classes which I'm importing to a PyDev (Jython ) project. They seem to work seamlessly except for Auto completion. The member functions of Java Classes do not auto-complete e.g. pressing the dot '.' operator does not bring up the list for class member functions. The jar file is added to the PyDev-PYTHONPATH external libraries of the PyDev project.

[Screenshot of PYTHONPATH external libs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23776836/classpath.jpg)

Auto completion does not work for the code below, but it compiles and runs perfectly fine.

```
from my.testpackage import MyClass

myVar = MyClass("Monkey")

print myVar.getName()
```

Typing "myVar." does not auto complete

Worth noting that auto completion works if I imported a non custom jar

e.g.

```
from java.lang import Math

print Math.max(3,5)
```

Typing "Math." will auto complete

I'm not sure if this functionality even supported in the current version of PyDev. Does anyone actually have this working in their PyDev and Eclipse setup?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you,

DM

Comment: you need to elaborate the problem a little more..if possible add the code with the import lines. Also how have you configured your java build path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be some issue in your PYTHONPATH configuration. Have you read: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html (most specifically the end of the page: "Project reference for Jython users").

If that doesn't help you, can you explain how are you referencing things? (a screenshot with the config would be nice)

Comment: I was able to get auto complete working by following the "Project reference for Jython users" instruction, but what I noticed was that the reason auto complete works is because of the .java source files in the referenced project. Auto complete doesn't seem to depend on the .class or jar files. Ultimately, I want to be able to reference a third party JAR file and have auto complete as well as error highlighting working.

Comment: I don't really want to do this but, I could probably decompile the class files contained in the jar, and use those decompiled java files to create a new project so it can be referenced by a PyDev project.

Comment: Actually, the code-completion that PyDev uses for Java is given by the JDT plugin, so, if you create a project and configure it properly in JDT and then make a reference to that project from PyDev, things should work out (without needing to decompile the project nor anything like that). The only thing is that you also need to make that project a PyDev project so that it knows what needs to be added to the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: source folders, external source folder and jars).

Comment: Just to clarify, auto complete works if I reference to a Java project. Auto complete still does not work if I download a third party JAR file from the web and add it to the PyDev project PYTHONPATH External Libraries. So far the only solution is to decompile the jar and create a new project from it so that it can be referenced by a PyDev project.

Comment: Actually, instead of decompiling, create a new java project, add the .jar in the jdt build path, then set that project as a pydev project, add the .jar in the source folder > add zip/jar/egg and reference that project from your pydev project.

Comment: I followed your instruction, but I can't seem  to "add the .jar in the source folder > add zip/jar/egg". When adding zip/jar/egg to the Source Folder (Source Folder tab), I'm not allowed to browse outside of the PyDev project directory. I added the .jar as an External Libraries (in the PyDev project) instead, but auto complete still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: You have to configure the project that has the .jar as a pydev project first and add it as a source folder there (and then reference that project from your original project).

Comment: I thought you meant add it as source folder for the original project. I corrected it, but auto complete only partially working (I get the same result if I add the jar to the external libraries of my original proj). I get an auto complete list of only "public static methods and variables".

Comment: So it turns out that auto complete doesn't work for some of the classes in the referenced jar (auto complete works perfectly for the rest of the classes in the jar). A little info on the the JAR file that I'm referencing; it's packaged and distributed by IBM. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please report that as a bug in the sf tracker explaining the proper setup to reproduce it.